# puedo retornar un JSON si tengo que agregar el contentType y processData? AJAX, JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Es que intento enviar archivos desde Ajax, jquery. Pero para esto debo de tener el processData y el contentType en (false), pero esto me causa un problema a la hora de retornar el valor en JSON, y es que quiero que se envíen tanto los datos del nombre y codigo y además el archivo, pero no sé si tambien debo de cambiar el processData y el contentType. QUIERO RECALCAR QUE TODOS LOS ARCHIVOS ESTAN POR SEPARADO, el html, php y el javascript

```js
$('#id_form').submit(function(e){
      
            
      var FormData = new FormData($('#id_form')[0]);
      
      $.ajax({
          data: FormData,
          url: 'prueba/enviar/',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json', //Quiero que me retorne en JSON, pero aunque agrege el dataType, no me functiona 
          contentType: false,//Estos dos campos se usan para el envío de archivos
          processData: false,//Estos dos campos se usan para el envío de archivos
          success: function(respuesta){

            $('#mostrarResultadoJSON').html(response[0]); //Supongamos que es así. Pero lo que quiero es que me traiga un objeto y no un texto

          }
           
      })
      
      
  
      e.preventDefault();
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- <form id='id_form' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> -->
    
    <input type="file" name="archivos[]" id="archivos" multiple>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">
    <input type="number" name="codigo" id="codigo">
    <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

    <div><p id="mostrarResultadoJSON"></p></div>

</body>
</html>

<?php

$archivo=$_FILES['archivos'];
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$codigo=$_POST['codigo'];

if(isset($archivo['tmp_name'] && isset($nombre) && isset($codigo))){
    $respuestaModelo=$this->modelo->enviarDato([archivoABinario($archivo), $nombre, $codigo]);

    if($respuestaModelo){

        echo  json_encode(['Se ha enviado el archivo']);
    }else{
        echo  json_encode(['No se ha enviado el archivo']);
    }
    
}


?>
```

ya le he agregado el accept, pero tampoco me ha funcionado

Comment: Tienes comentado el formulario `<!-- <form id='id_form' method="POST"> -->`, descoméntalo y debe funcionar sin problema.

Comment: No puedes tener nada de HTML en tu segundo código, debe ser un PHP cuya única salida sea el `echo` con el json.

Comment: @Triby sí, lo sé, lo comenté aquí, para que vieran pudieran ver el Form

Comment: No estás usando Ajax correctamente. Su propósito es poder enviar/recibir datos entre cliente y servidor sin necesidad de recargar la página. Para eso el archivo que pones en el parámetro `url` debe ser un archivo PHP aparte del archivo donde está el formulario. Y ese archivo no debería sacar nada por pantalla, solamente la información que sea generada cuando se procesen los datos. Aquí parece que quieres usar el mismo archivo del formulario para procesar los datos. Ajax no funciona de esa manera.

Comment: @A.Cedano te entiendo. Pero lo que pasa es que el archivo php SÍ está por aparte. De hecho todos los archivos estan por separado, lo que quiero es mostrar cómo llegan

Comment: No hay problema en eso, FormData te permite enviar tanto archivos como datos simples, ese es su propósito precisamente. Pero debes cumplir ciertos criterios: 1º. El `form` debe ser declarado como `multipart`; 2º. Si usas Ajax debes hacer lo que te comenté anteriormente para manejar los datos; 3º Debes quitar el intento de recibir los datos en la página donde está el formulario, me refiero a este código y similar: `$archivo=$_FILES['archivos'];  ...` no tiene ningún sentido ahí, eso debes hacerlo en el archivo (o url si usas url amigables) que pongas aquí: `url: 'prueba/enviar/'`

Comment: Dos cosas importantes: 1) Defines el nombre como `archivos[]` y el campo no tiene atributo `multiple`. 2) ¿Cómo procesas el archivo? deberías tener en cuenta que el campo te llega como arreglo.

Comment: jejeje fue error mio no colocarlo, pero en el original sí lo tengo